# Databricks: Merge dataframe into Azure synapse table

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse

Are there any way we can merge dataframe into A table of Azure Synapse ??
what I found for datarame.write.mode()

only allow append and overwrite ... Are there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant upsert: Synapse does not support `upsert`

You'll have to do your own `delete` followed by `insert` to mimic upsert.

This assumes your new data is complete (i.e. it doesn't only container changes column values, but has all column values). If not then you'll have to read another dataframe from Synapse, merge them in Spark/Databricks and then do an upsert.

You can also do this using a staging table in Synapse and use Synapse's compute to do the upsert instead of Spark's compute.

---

> If not then you'll have to read another dataframe from Synapse, merge them in Spark/Databricks and then do an upsert.

To elaborate:

If you have this in DB:

```
k,a,b
1,1,1
2,2,2
```

This is the dataframe (say `df_new`) you're trying to write to DB:

```
k,a
1,11
3,3
```

And this is what you expect DB to look like after update:

```
k,a,b
1,11,1
2,2,2
3,3,null
```

Then you need to create a dataframe `df_current_db` that has:

```
k,a,b
1,1,1
```

NOTE: You only need keys that exist in `df_new` not all.

Then merge `df_current_db` and `df_new` to create a new `df_upsert` which has:

```
k,a,b
1,11,1
3,3,null
```

Finally you have to upsert:

- `delete from DB where k in (select k from df_upsert)`
- `insert into DB (select * from df_upsert)`

Comment: "If not then you'll have to read another dataframe from Synapse, merge them in Spark/Databricks and then do an upsert."  << what mean ?upsert within dataframe in databricks ?

Comment: @mytabi Updated to elaborate. HTH.

Comment: df_upsert need to put back to Synapse database first ? before doing delete and insert ?
coz I think delete and insert can't do directly to the dataframe that read from synapse....

Comment: @mytabi putting `df_upsert` into DB is the last step `insert into DB (select * from df_upsert)`. And yes, changing dataframe has no effect on DB contents unless you `write` the dataframe to DB.